# Mysql function to transform non-null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know if mysql have a function which receives two arguments, if the first is null, it returns null otherwise it returns the second.

It would be a shortcut for `if(something is null, null, anotherthing)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think there is some misunderstanding. `coalesce` returns the first non-null value, or null if there is no non-null value, right? I want to transform a non-null value, or return null if it is null. It is similar to the `fmap` behavior on `Maybe` values in Haskell

Comment: No, there's no function for that, but you can probably write your own.

Comment: @dnoeth It is the answer. Very simple ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no function for yor behavior, but it is simple to create your own function if you have the permissions for that, other wise you could also add an `IF THEN ELSE` to your query like you already showed but that would be no answer for your question. If you want to create a function then you will have the problem that you need explicit parameter types and with mysql it is unfortunately also not functional to overload a function (same function name but different parameter types). So you need for different types different functions with different function names. It would look like that:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION `fmap_varchar`(e1 VARCHAR(255), e2 VARCHAR(255) )
    RETURNS VARCHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC
    RETURN IF(e1 IS NULL, NULL, e2);
```

You would have maybe also to take care for the correct charset which you can also specify at the returns clause.

And the solution with a query you gave already:

```
    SELECT IF(something IS NULL, NULL, anotherthing) FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Thank you for understanding the core of the problem

Comment: Sorry that I could not find better solutions because I also do not like such statements within queries, but I wanted at least bunch all together. MySQL is nice for small projects or with standard features, but customizing with such low requirements is sometimes annoying. But every DBMS has cons and pros.