# Mysql - transforming non-null values part 2

Tags: mysql, sql

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36341679/mysql-function-to-transform-non-null-values) I asked if Mysql have a function which receives two arguments and returns `null` if the first is `null` or the second argument otherwise. Somebody said in the comment section that such function doesn't exist. How can I define this function in Mysql, considering that it may receive arguments of any type and the return value can be null or of the same type of the second parameter? Is it even possible?

Comment: `select case when arg1 is null
            then null
            else arg2
       end`

Comment: The simplest method is `(case when arg1 is not null then arg2 end)`.  A function that you seem to want is `nvl2()` from Oracle.

Comment: MySQL supports [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce), which will work for this if I'm understanding you correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, given your or requirements.

The arguments and return values of stored functions (written in SQL) and user-defined functions (written in C) are all statically typed.

Granted, MySQL is pretty flexible with implicit casting, but the values are typed nonetheless.  Even if you were okay with implicit casting, a scenario where that would be preferable to the seemingly-obvious solution is difficult to imagine.

`IF(foo IS NULL,foo,bar)` would suffice for the purpose and preserve the underlying types correctly, and `IF(foo IS NULL,NULL,bar)` would be almost the same thing, though the type of foo would be lost (e.g a "it's a NULL DATETIME").

You have previously rejected those, for reasons that are not intuitively obvious.  When a purpose can be accomplished with built-ins, the motivation to reinvent the wheel is hard to understand.

Comment: It is not what I want, I want to make a function that receives only two arguments, and you are only explaining that I should get used with this `if` function because I can't achieve my goal. The reason I want to do it is quite straight forward, I have this case: `coalesce(if(isNull(sale.id), null, 'related to a sale'), if(isNull(purchace.id), null, 'related to a purchase')...)`, because I am doing some left joins to get a payment context, for some reason which is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: *Facepalm.* Why didn't you say so?  Your solution simple: `CASE WHEN sale.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'related to a sale' WHEN purchase.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'related to a purchase' ELSE 'related to funny cat videos' END`. The first match in a `CASE` expression determines the result... just like the first non-NULL argument to `COALESCE()`. You, my friend, seem to have treated us to a classic [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info), asking about your attempted solution, rather than the actual problem.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to help. I would like to 'wrap the null context itself' and treat only what is specific, like the monad way of thinking from Haskell does, I don't want all that boilerplate, everything you showed I've already considered, I would like to know if I could solve it like this `coalesce(f(sale.id, 'related to a sale'), f(purchase.id, 'related to a purchase'))`. Everybody here is failing to understand that there is a context of `null` or `absence` which I would like to treat intuitively, like the Haskell Maybe monad does, but in SQL...

Comment: In Perl, my $string = $this || $that sets $string to $that if $this is undefined or empty or otherwise false, and sets $string to $this otherwise.  I mention that point precisely because it is comparatively irrelevant.  This is SQL, not any other language.

Comment: While I appreciate theoretically elegant and/or intuitive/expressive solutions as much as the next guy, you do seem to be beating a dead horse somewhat mercilessly.  Had you asked your actual question, the most intuitive and elegant  answer is the `CASE` expression in my comment, above.  The point of my answer, though, is not "don't do it your way, do it my way" but rather that MySQL cannot satisfy what you want, if you insist on the function being data type agnostic.  Given known/fixed types, a stored function is easy enough.

Comment: I surrender, this little simple function should exist but doesn't. I already said I appreciate your attempt to help, but actually you did only help with the first line: 'This is not possible, given your requirements.'. In the rest of your answer, you just tried to explain why I should use a less elegant approach, for now I will use this less elegant approach.

Comment: `CREATE FUNCTION foo (arg1 LONGTEXT, arg2 LONGTEXT) RETURNS LONGTEXT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL RETURN CASE WHEN arg1 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE arg2 END;` Done.  Integers will cast implicitly to longtext, no problem.

Comment: It is a satisfactory answer, even though it is not exactly what I asked for, please, post it as an answer.

Comment: Will do.  Shutting down for the night, I'll try to pick this back up tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select IF(ISNULL(arg1), null, arg2)
```

Read more about [Comparison Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html) and [Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html).

Comment: It has a lot of boilerplate, and I already stated about the approach you are suggesting in my previous answer. I would like to define a function `myFunction(x, y)` which would follow my question requirements, not use this IF function.